# Flutter: Ultimate responsive Layout for mobile devices

Tags: flutter, layout, overflow, responsive

since I am learning **Flutter** now for about a year, I am using several responsive layout functions to be sure that my app looks fine on each device. Normally, I am using **MediaQuery** with a factor for Containers and Cards and if I have Text inside, I use **FittedBox** with BoxFit.contain. So far, it works well, but from time to time I get an **overflow**, e.g. when my colleague opens the app on his IPhone 12 Emulator. Yesterday, he had an overflow inside the bottom nav bar. It was because of the icons and I do not know why this appears. I gave the bottom bar a defined height with MediaQuery and wrapped the icons inside fitted boxes. After that, I defined the icon size with Media Query as well, still no real improvment. The title, or the label is not displayed.

**Well my question would be a general one:** Since I have no real experience with other languages, I am not able to compare the effort which is neccessary to have a responsive layout to other languages, but maybe an experienced developer can give me some tips how to improve the workflow of having a responsive layout. We want to launch in the app stores in August and the fear of having overflows on several devices drives me crazy. In this case, it is more a responsiveness to many mobile devices rather than having a good layout on mobile, desktop, tablet. So please, tell me about your approaches. It would really help me!

Regards!

Answer (score 1):

See for responsive design, try to use the **Padding** and the **Expanded** Widgets the Most.

They are most useful when designing responsive screens.

Also, you can see other layout widgets [here](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/ui/widgets/layout).

Dont use specific pixels (numbers) to limit the size of anything, try making it dynamic based on screen size.

Between phone and desktop, make 2 layouts and switch them as needed.

Between different sized phones, padding should do the work.